# Is it possible to add multiple materials to a text object?

Tags: materials

I know that for a mesh you can go into edit mode and select vertices and assign a specific material to them quite easily. I want to know if it is possible to do this with a Text object (which has no vertices).

Comment: good one. nice find.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this by going into edit mode and moving using the arrow keys and holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> to select which characters to assign to, all other steps are the same.

[image: Text Material Example]