# Extracting a text string info (character's indices) to use it as a material mask

Tags: python, cycles-render-engine, scripting, materials

I think an image can say more than words sometimes... :)
[image: setup!]
The idea is to use a different color from the color ramp for each character in the string.
It's related to this [question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/27240/11431)

Comment: so you need the index of the currently rendered character not just the char index

Comment: i guess you're right :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The color of each character is determined by the material index on the text object. Therefore, to have each character use a different color from the color ramp requires a material for each color.

The steps involved:

- A material for each color in the color ramp node.
- The text object must have all the materials applied to it.
- The characters must reference the index of the materials.

This script takes the colors from a color ramp node, makes new materials and then assign each character a material.

```
import bpy

txt = 'Text' # The name of text object and text curve.
materials = bpy.data.objects[txt].data.materials
i = 0

# This material holds the color ramp node, change 'material name' to the name of your material.
rampMat = 'material name'
colorRamp = bpy.data.materials[rampMat].node_tree.nodes['ColorRamp'].color_ramp.elements

# Convert colors from the ramp to materials and add them to the text object.
for element in colorRamp:
    color = element.color
    material = bpy.data.materials.new('color')
    material.diffuse_color = color[0], color[1], color[2]
    materials.append(material)

# Loop through the characters setting their indexes.
for character_format in bpy.data.curves[txt].body_format:
    character_format.material_index = i % len(materials)
    i += 1
```

[image: regular text and colorRamp node with the colors]

[image: colored text after running the above script.]

Comment: because it looks awesome

Comment: @Chebhou it was a little tongue in cheek, I just wrote the script to do exactly that.

Comment: This looks like what i wanted, with some awsomeness, thanks!!  I'll check this tomorrow. If you want to animate this, you can answer [this question](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/27240/11431) too :)

Comment: easy to use, simple. That's really cool!