# Possible to control text color in the text editor?

Tags: add-on, text-object

I'm using the [Typewriter Addon](https://gitlab.com/bkurdali/blender-addon-experiments) to fake an RPG-like UI for some animation. The text is pulled from a text file... what I'm wondering is if there's some way to markup the text in the file to control the color so I can use a few different colors.[image: very silly]

Comment: My answer [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/27275/2217) may be of some help.

Comment: brilliant... this looks like what i need. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

So @David's comment I think points you in the right direction, but maybe it can be made a little simpler.

Basically you can give individual characters (or words, or sentences, etc.) different materials (i.e. material indexes).  Each material can, obviously, vary not only in color but any attribute you can put into a material.

So, with the text object below, in edit mode I highlight the characters I wish to give a new material.

[image: text in edit mode]

You can add a new material slot if you need one, create a new material if you need one, etc., but at the end of the day all you need to do to assign the selected text to the chosen material slot is to click the "Assign" button.

You've then got text with different materials!

[image]

Comment: thank for the reply, but this doesn't work with the typewriter addon, i guess because it's dynamically editing the text. i suppose I could try keyframing the materials as the letters are added, but I may try @David's solution first.