# How to assign materials to a text via Python

Tags: python, materials, text-object

I want to assign different materials to a *single* text object via Python. This can be done manually by selecting the desired Material slot, typing away, choosing a different material slot and typing further. But how can I do this via Python?

Comment: related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27240/is-it-possible-to-animate-which-characters-of-a-text-object-are-assigned-to-a-ma?rq=1

Comment: don't mark this as duplicate of "How to assign a new material to an object in the scene from Python".  This question is more specific and is covered to a large extent by question 27240 that i linked to.

Comment: @zeffii - your link pointed me in the right direction, thanks!